# Android billiard textures. The best way to program?

Tags: android, background

I'm making billiard on android.
I don't know how to program background. Temporary solution I made:

```
private void checkEdges()
{
    if(ballY-radius-edge <= 0 || ballY+radius+edge >= MainActivity.screenWidth)
        vy *= -1;
    if(ballX-radius-edge <= 0 || ballX+radius+edge >= MainActivity.screenHeight)
        vx *= -1;
}
```

I have background image with billiard table and I checked what is the size of screen and edge of table billiard. It's working, but I think it isn't great solution, because on other device an edge can have other size.

My another idea was to cut image with billiard table on small pieces and then check coordinates of them, but I don't know how to locate these pieces in right places.

What is the best and right idea how to program it ? 
Of course then I will programming holes in my billiard, so now I want to program the background in the right way, to won't have any issues later.